# Keeps showing Undefined name 'Stripe' while trying to add publishable key

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments

I'm adding Stripe payment to an app I'm building. I've added the Stripe package, imported it and made sure all the requirements are met. But when I try to add publishable key using Stripe.publishableKey, it's showing: Undefined name 'Stripe'. This is the the code in my main.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
...
import 'package:flutter_stripe/flutter_stripe.dart'; //.....stripe package import....


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Stripe.publishableKey = publishableKey;  //.....Undefined name 'Stripe'.......
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ThemeProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ApplicationState()),
      ],
      child: Consumer<ThemeProvider>(
        builder: (context, _themeProvider, snapshot) {
          return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Title',
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: themeLight(context),
            darkTheme: themeDark(context),
            themeMode: (_themeProvider.isDarkTheme == true)
                ? ThemeMode.dark
                : ThemeMode.light,
            initialRoute: '/',
            routes: {
              '/': (context) => const SplashScreen(),
              '/on-boarding': (context) => const OnBoardingScreen(),
              '/all-login-options': (context) =>
                  const SocialNetworkSignInScreen(),
              ...
              '/home': (context) => const Home(),
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Has anyone ever faced a similar issue before? Do you have any solutions for it? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can give the import a name and use it to access the Stripe class. this is the solution I came up with when facing the same issue

```
import 'package:flutter_stripe/flutter_stripe.dart' as stripe;
```

and then in main

```
stripe.Stripe.publishableKey = publishableKey;
```